# CUCM 10.5 - Reset Admin name & password

Tags: cisco, voip, cisco-voip

I need to reset my CUCM Admin password and name.  On previous versions of Cisco Call Manager, I had to log in to CLI and run these commands :

```
utils reset_ui_administrator_name
utils reset_ui_administrator_password
```

But it seems as they do not exist anymore in 10.5. At least the CLI does not support them.

Can somebody confirm this? Also, is there a way to work around this issue? (I know about password recovery but that is not what I need).

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use:

```
utils reset_application_ui_administrator_name
```

and

```
utils reset_application_ui_administrator_password
```

To confuse things a bit, the latest install guide [Installing Cisco Unified Communications Manager, Release 10.0(1)](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucm/install/10_0_1/CUCM_BK_I95AD2FE_00_installing-cucm-100.pdf) indicates you can use `utils reset ui administrator name` and  `utils reset ui administrator password` but those are also not available on my lab servers.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to recover the security, admin and app passwords on a CUCM (or other UCOS host) as opposed to resetting them.  If running on VMWare, take a snapshot just in case.  Boot the UCOS host using a Linux rescue CD and extract this file...

```
/usr/local/platform/conf/platformConfig.xml
```

and copy to your server. An alternative that doesn't involve downtime is to issue the command:

```
utils create report platform
```

Then follow the instructions to upload to an SFTP server.

You can then use the UCOS Password Decrypter app to open the file.  It will show you the decrypted passwords.  You can download it here...

http://www.adhdtech.com/uctools.html

This way you don't go through the headache of resetting the cluster security password on your pub & subs.  To perform the actual copy of the XML file to a Windows host, I boot the UCOS host with a CentOS Live ISO, configure a temp static IP then start the SSHD service.  From there I use WinSCP on my Windows box to connect to the CentOS live session and extract the file.

Answer (score -1):

`set password user admin` is the new command